# Use of undeclared identifier Core-Data Entity Subclass (NSManaged Object)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Im fairly new in Core-Data, sry. My Core-Data Entity has a subclass "CachedWeatherDataEntity" which derives from NSManagedObject. I import the "CachedWeatherDataEntity.h"-file in my protocol "WeatherDataCache". This protocol defines methods for saving/fetching data and sets the Core-Data "core-functionality". but now the compiler cant find my Entity in the corresponding implementation "WeatherDataCacheImpl". Error is on the end of the code. This app is based on [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started).

**CachedWeatherDataEntity.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface CachedWeatherDataEntity : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * airHumidity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * airPressure;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * dateTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * illuminance;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * precipitation;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * radiation1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * radiation2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * sunDown;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * sunUp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * temperature;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * windDirection;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * windSpeed;

@end
```

**CachedWeatherDataEntity.m**

```
#import "CachedWeatherDataEntity.h"


@implementation CachedWeatherDataEntity

@dynamic airHumidity;
@dynamic airPressure;
@dynamic dateTime;
@dynamic illuminance;
@dynamic precipitation;
@dynamic radiation1;
@dynamic radiation2;
@dynamic sunDown;
@dynamic sunUp;
@dynamic temperature;
@dynamic windDirection;
@dynamic windSpeed;

@end
```

**WeatherDataCache.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "WeatherDataSet.h"
#import "CachedWeatherDataEntity.h"

@protocol WeatherDataCache <NSObject>

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (id<WeatherDataSet>) getData:(NSDate*)pDateTime;

- (void) saveDataArray:(NSMutableArray*)pDataArray;

- (void) saveData:(id<WeatherDataSet>)pData;

- (void)saveContext;

- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
@end
```

**WeatherDataCacheImpl.h**

```
#import  <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "WeatherDataCache.h"
#import "WeatherDataSetImpl.h"

@interface WeatherDataCacheImpl : NSObject <WeatherDataCache> {

}
@end
```

**WeatherDataCacheImpl.m** +++ Here's the error +++

```
#import "WeatherDataCacheImpl.h"
#import "CachedWeatherDataEntity.h"


@implementation WeatherDataCacheImpl

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;


- (id<WeatherDataSet>) getData:(NSDate*)pDateTime {

    return nil;
}

- (void) saveDataArray:(NSMutableArray*)pDataArray {

    double temp = 23.3;
    double air = 95.0;
    NSDate *myDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];




    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    CachedWeatherDataEntity *CachedWeatherDataEntity = [NSEntityDescription
                                      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CachedWeatherDataEntity"
                                      inManagedObjectContext:context];
    CachedWeatherDataEntity.temperature = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:temp];
    CachedWeatherDataEntity.airHumidity = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:air];
    CachedWeatherDataEntity.dateTime = myDate;



    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    // Test listing all CachedWeatherDataEntitys from the store
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CachedWeatherDataEntity"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];



    for (CachedWeatherDataEntity *info in fetchedObjects) { <-----------Use of undeclared identifier 'info'

        NSLog(@"temp: %@", info.temp);        
        NSLog(@"air: %@", info.air);
    }
}
```

Comment: I usually put my core data methods in my AppDelegate so that they are accessible by views and controllers. Have you seen the CoreDataBooks or ThreadedCoreData samples on Apple's dev site? Finally, you call your entity by that name, yet you call *info on CachedWeather... Is that correct? Have you tried "entity.info.temp"?

Comment: not shure. i really should take a look into the books, because sooner i will need the entities to display diagrams and to zoom into them for more details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one problem is here:

```
CachedWeatherDataEntity *CachedWeatherDataEntity = ...
```

because the local variable has the same name as the class. You should rename
the variable, e.g. to lower-case:

```
CachedWeatherDataEntity *cachedWeatherDataEntity = ...
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Too much refactoring, previously. thats the cause. thanks a lot!